# Checking Values in Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I made a Sub. But its giving an error.!
I want to check if column A has values then it checks for columns" H and I ". those must be filled. 
Else the file wont save..!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim oneRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If cell.Value(Range("A8:A" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cell In Range("H8:I" & LastRow)
            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Please Select Value from Dropdown Menu...." & cell.Address
                Application.Goto cell
                Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRIED AND TESTED**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("receivings")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A8:A" & lRow)) = 0 _
        Then Exit Sub

        For Each aCell In Range("H8:I" & lRow)
            If IsEmpty(aCell.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Please Select Value from Dropdown Menu...." _
                & aCell.Address

                Application.Goto aCell
                Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next aCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It says subscript out of Range.

Comment: Did you change `Sheet1` to the relevant sheetname?

Comment: Its sheet1 only.. I just renamed my sheet1 (receivings)

Comment: Change the line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` to `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("receivings")`

Comment: Well, I gotta step out for dinner. Will keep an eye on this thread via my phone so I might be late in replying to your comments...

Comment: sry, doesnt work.. it sayd. Run-time error '1004'............................ Method 'Range' of object _Global Failed

Comment: I suppose/.. if I write "For Each aCell In range("H8" & LastRow)"   "For Each aCell In range("H8:H" & LastRow).. I get the result.. But, it doesnt solve my purpose..! i.e. I want that it should check if Column A is filled then Columns H and I are mandatory to be filled.. else it wont save the file..

Answer (score 0):

sheet1 and sheets(1) is often not the same. Best is using the name of the sheet.
You might miss a "." at the second for (...in .range...) ?

PS, i'm new in VBA, what does application.goto aCell, do ? because it strage to put a "exit for" after a "goto"...